# Let $f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be continuous such that $f(a) \ge b,\, f(b) \le a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be continuous such that $f(a) \ge b,\, f(b) \le a$. Then $\exists x \in [a,b]$ such that
>
> (A)$f(x)=0$
>
> (B)$f(x)=x$
>
> (C)$f'(x)=0$
>
> (D)$f''(x)=0$

I am not sure how to tackle it. I was trying to construct a function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and was trying to apply intermediate value theorem but could not get success.
Can someone explain?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You have $g(a) > 0 > g(b)$. Hence $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$.

Comment: The answer is B. The easiest way to see it is to draw the picture. Put the line $y=x$ in your picture, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct idea. Note that $g(x) = f(x)-x$ satisfies $g(a) = f(a)-a \geq b - a > 0$ and $g(b) = f(b)-b \leq a - b < 0$. In other words, a continuous function $g(x)$ satisfies $g(a) < 0 < g(b)$ on some interval $[a,b]$.

Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Any of the others don't work. If $a > 0$, option (A) is clearly false. Moreover, we are given that $f$ is continuous, not that it is differentiable, so $f'$ and $f''$ may not exist, and thus (C), (D) are not guaranteed as well.